# Override ASP MVC EditorFor template and include original EditorFor arguments?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, templates, editorfor

I'm currently overriding the EditorFor helper with a custom one that displays a DateTime object as an empty string if the DateTime object has a min-value set. It does this using TextBoxFor helper:

```
<%: Html.TextBox("", (Model != DateTime.MinValue ? Model.Date.ToString("ddMMMyy") : string.Empty), new { @class = "edit-date-field" })%>
```

The problem is that when I use this like this:

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(m => m.StartDate, new { id = "field-id", @class = "field-class"})%>
```

i expected MVC to preserve the field-id and field-class attributes, but instead the generated element has id="StartDate" and only one class, class="edit-date-field".

So, how do I preserve the attributes that are included in the original call to EditorFor? If I add the original id and class attributes into the template, than ALL calls to EditorFor with a DateTime object will get that specific elements/value pair which is not what I want.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let me clarify, you are trying to use **TextBox** to replace the **EditorFor**.

Your original **TextBox** html helper does not have id set and the class attribute was set to **edit-date-field**

Try this:

```
<%: Html.TextBox("field-id", (Model != DateTime.MinValue ? Model.Date.ToString("ddMMMyy") : string.Empty), new { @class = "field-class" })%>
```